# C++, a simpler way to check 3 arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, max

I have 3 arrays,

> int fJump[13], sJump[13], tJump[13];

each one of them has jumps recorded in them. I'm in need to check whether one of them is bigger than `max`, to get the biggest value.

So I could make it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(max<fJump[i]){
            max = fJump[i];
        }
        if(max<sJump[i]){
            max = sJump[i];
        }
        if(max<tJump[i]){
            max = tJump[i];
        }
    }
```

but sometimes there are a lot more, so writing like this is a headache. Would there be a nicer and quicker solution to do that?

Comment: What is a "jump" in this context?

Comment: Long jump, like in the olympics

Comment: Maybe creating an array of arrays and then scan all them with two nested FOR cycles?

Comment: @RnD: That's a pretty spectacular feat of spatial physics, putting such an action into an array of integers in computer memory. Can you do the same with my cat's last meow?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit yea, I'll tell that to my professor next time I see him

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) function from the standard library instead of writing your own loop:

```
int max = *std::max_element(fJump, fJump+13);
max = std::max(max, *std::max_element(sJump, sJump+13));
max = std::max(max, *std::max_element(tJump, tJump+13));
```

You can also use the `max` function inside your loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    max = std::max(max, fJump[i]);
    max = std::max(max, sJump[i]);
    max = std::max(max, tJump[i]);
}
```

Comment: Write `std::max` to avoid any conflicts. This is _why_ we have namespaces; let's use them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is an excellent suggestion, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
int * arrs[]={fJump, sJump, tJump};
int max=arrs[0][0];
for(int j=0; j<sizeof(arrs)/sizeof(*arrs); j++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(max<arrs[j][i])
            max=arrs[j][i];
    }
}
```

and you can put as many `int` pointers as you want in `arrs` (as long as they all come from arrays of the same size - namely `n`).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: of course, but they have to be pointers to first element of an array (and all of the same size), not any random `int` pointers you can have. Still, reworded a bit for clarity.

Comment: Yes, but they are certainly not arrays, which is what your answer claimed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: that's the same old story... `fJump`, `sJump` and `tJump` are arrays (so what you *write* in the initialization list are arrays), but in that context they decay to pointers. Anyway, I reworded that phrase for clarity *and* formal correctness.

Comment: Well, they're _names of arrays_, which is not the same thing ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: for some reason every discussion about arrays in C or C++ seems to degenerate in a discussion about ontology... `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

```
int fJump[13], sJump[13], tJump[13];
int * pA[] = { fJump, sJump, tJump };

int l = sizeof(pA)/sizeof(pA[0]);

for(int i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < l; ++j)
    {
        if(max < pA[j][i])
        {
            max = pA[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int a1[] = { 7,3,1,29,5 };
  int a2[] = { 11,12,18,5,4,3 };
  int a3[] = { 10,10,11,10 };

  std::vector< int > allMax{
    *std::max_element( a1, a1+5 ),
    *std::max_element( a2, a2+6 ),
    *std::max_element( a3, a3+4 ),
    };

  auto maxOfAll = *std::max_element( allMax.begin(), allMax.end() );

  std::cout << maxOfAll << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can handle it with an array of array of int type.